# CodeIgniter attach email function issue

Tags: php, email, codeigniter-3, email-attachments

It would be appreciated if you help me with following code as I follow correct step but still not receiving email with attachment.

Will be appreciated if any of you find the correct issue.

**Here is smtp setting of email:**

```
$config = array(
                "protocol"   => "SMTP",
                "smtp_host"  => "domainname.com",
                "smtp_port"  => "465",
                "smtp_timeout"  => "7",
                "smtp_user"  => 'sales@domainname.com',
                "smtp_pass"  => "password", 
                "starttls"   => TRUE,
                "charset"    => "iso-8859-1",
                "mailtype"   => "html", 
                "wordwrap"   => TRUE,
                "newline"    => "\r\n",
                "validate"   => FALSE,
                "smtp_keep_alive" => TRUE
            );
            
            $this->load->library('email', $config);
```

and there is send email setting, note that i have upload file getting file path through `DOCUMENT_ROOT` but still not getting email with attachment only empty email with content provided

```
$this->email->from($Data['Email'], $Data['Name']);
                    $this->email->to('sales@domainname.com');
                    $this->email->subject(sprintf('Email Send by - %s', $Data['Name']));
                    $this->email->message(sprintf('
                        Request ID: %s <br />
                        Name: %s <br />
                        Email: %s<br />
                        Colors: %s <br />
                        Quantity: %s<br />
                        Phone: %s<br />
                        Message: %s <br />
                        Target Price: %s'
                    , $PK,$Data['Name'], $Data['Email'], $Data['Colors'], $Data['Quantity'], $Data['Phone'], $Input->post('Config')['Message'],$Data['TargetPrice']));
                    //attachment
                    if($Row){
                         $ImagePath = GetFileRootPath($Row->EntryDate,'IMG',false,$Row->Image);;
                         // this function is returning this path - /home/User/public_html/domainname.com/resources/upload/img/2023/11/24/download.jpg
                         if($ImagePath){
                            $this->email->attach($ImagePath);
                            
                         }
                    }
                    
                    if($this->email->send()){
                        SetMessage('ENTRYSUCCESS');
                    } else {
                        SetMessage('ENTRYFAILED');
                    }
                
                } else{
                    SetMessage('ENTRYFAILED');
                }
```

again mentioning below the return of GetFileRootPath function so its easy to read:
/home/User/public_html/domainname.com/resources/upload/img/2023/11/24/download.jpg

this is what i am sending in attach function but still getting email without attachment.

Comment: Have you checked the path is correct?

Comment: `$ImagePath` needs to be your website downloadable URL, something like this: `<https://example.com/user-uploads/image-name.jpg`, and make sure when this URL is clicked either file needs to be open or downloaded.

Comment: No, path does not need to be a downloadable URL.  It just needs to be the internal path to the file.  This is for an attachment not a embedded image in the email.

Comment: The code per se looks fine. Are you sure `$ImagePath` is correct, the file exists and `$this->email->attach($ImagePath);` is really executed? Add some debugging output (especially immediately befor or after exectuing the `->attach`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you logged the path to make sure it is getting set?

```
if($ImagePath){
    log_message($ImagePath);
    $this->email->attach($ImagePath);
}
```

Unless you are checking somewhere else I would suggest checking to make sure file exists.

```
if(is_file($ImagePath)){
    $this->email->attach($ImagePath);
}
```

Check the permissions of the file to make sure the account user has rights to it.

Try attaching a simple text file instead of a image file to see if its something with the file itself.  The receiving server may be stripping it out.

BTW, you have an extra semicolon here:

```
$ImagePath = GetFileRootPath($Row->EntryDate,'IMG',false,$Row->Image);;
```

Comment: This answer is requesting Debugging Details -- that is a reason to comment/close, not a reason to answer.

Comment: The answer is valid because there is nothing wrong with the code itself so the problem must lie in some other area.

Comment: @TomVaughan "*because there is nothing wrong with the code itself*" and that's why you should request additional debugging details in a comment and not in an answer ...

Answer (score 1):

Assume your file is in `assets/uploads/`, *(I Recommend inside the `assets` folder)*

I use the code below to open the file.

```
# test with normal file and add your original file path
$filePath = FCPATH . 'assets/uploads/download.jpg';
```

**[`FCPATH`](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/reserved_names.html?highlight=fcpath#constants) contains the absolute path to your project's root folder.**

And then use  `$this->email->attach($filePath);` to attach the file.

---

Example

```
$this->load->library('email');

$config = array(
    'protocol'  => 'SMTP',
    ....
    'mailtype'  => 'html',
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);

$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->from('email@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('recipient@example.com');
$this->email->subject('Email with Attachment');
$this->email->message('Testing Email with Attachment.....');

$filePath = FCPATH . 'assets/uploads/download.jpg'; 
$this->email->attach($filePath);

if($this->email->send()) {
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
}
```

Comment: Are you able to explicitly identify where the asker has made a mistake? This just reads like a how-to to me.